# TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Why am I getting this error?

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

This is my models.py file

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
Mobile_No = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
Proof = models.TextField()
viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-date"]
```

This is my views.py file

```
class RequestItem(generic.CreateView):
    model = UserNotification
    fields = ['Name', 'Mobile_No', 'Proof']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = super(UserNotification, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['Name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*Enter your name'})
        form.fields['Mobile_No'].widget = TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': "*Enter your's mobile number to get a call back from angel"})
        form.fields['Proof'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*enter proof you have for your lost item'})
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.kwargs)

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        qs = Report_item.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        self.object.user = qs[0].owner
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Your request has been processed</h1>")
```

I am using django 1.11. There was no error and code working properly until I add the placeholder function. After adding the placeholder I am getting this error. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is where you call `super()` inside `get_form`. You need to use the current class; for some reason you have put the model class there. It needs to be:

```
form = super(RequestItem, self).get_form(form_class)
```

Or better, since you are using Python 3, use the short version:

```
form = super().get_form(form_class)
```

Note however this isn't really a good way to do what you're trying to do here. Rather, declare an actual form class which sets the widget attributes for the fields you want to change, and refer to it in the view class by setting the `form_class` attribute at class level.

Comment: Well, you solved my problem. Thanks a ton for it. But why this not is really a good way to do. I used this way because I got an answer to do so on StackOverflow..